# RSpec Controller test converting hash into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller spec for my application, which tests the create method on a controller. The create action actually works fine, but the spec is failing. It seems that it is auto converting the the hash POST param into a string.

```
let(:coupon) { attributes_for(:coupon) }

describe 'POST #create' do
  it 'should create a new coupon from params' do
    expect {
      post :create, :coupon => coupon
    }.to change(Coupon, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Now, If I do `puts coupon` it is generating a valid hash of data, and the type is hash. For some reason the controller is receiving a string for params[:coupon]. Only in rspec testing does this happen, when I test in the browse with a POST form it works perfectly fine.

Rspec throws the following message:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x00000005062700>
   Did you mean?  print
```

and if I do `puts params[:coupon].class` in the controller in rspec it gives me String. Why might it be converting my hash into a string for the POST request, and how can I prevent this ?

I am using Rails 5.0.0 and rspec 3.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was an issue with the gem `open_taobao` somehow transforming my post requests in tests.

Answer (score 2):

This exact same behavior showed up for me recently when testing a JSON API endpoint.  Originally I had this as my subject:

```rb
subject { put :my_endpoint, **input_args }
```

and an integer value in `input_args` was getting translated into a string.  The fix was to add `format: 'json'` as an additional keyword argument to `put`:

```rb
subject { put :my_endpoint, **input_args, format: 'json' }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this did not fix, and I have already been trying to test it using various JSON functions. My entire coupon hash is being converted into string. In the controller, when using params.require(:coupon), it is getting a string rather than a hash so It cannot access any of the hash's values.